# How to imitate garbage collection in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a library that keeps an array of objects, the purpose is not really relevant to the issue. it looks like this:

```
window.Tracker = {
  objects: [],
  track: function(obj){
    this.objects.push(obj)
  }
}
```

In other parts of the app, Vue/React components constantly push objects to this library as they're loaded from a server:

```
this.movie = { id: 56456, name: "Avengers" }
Tracker.track(this.props.movie)
```

Overtime, the `Tracker.objects` array gets bigger and bigger, mostly because of objects no longer needed (their components no longer exist), and I really **don't** want to keep objects like this in the array.

The problem is I don't have control over anything aside from this Tracker library. (so I can't really make callbacks when the object is no longer needed)

But I need a way to garbage collect/ get rid of objects that are no longer used by anything other than in the `Tracker.objects` array.

Is this possible?

Comment: No it is not. You need to change the way, Tracker works.

Comment: `objects` is an array, so you can utilize array removers (unshift, pop, etc.)

Comment: I must be missing something. You say "Vue/React components constantly push objects to this library as they're loaded from a server" but then you say "The problem is I don't have control over anything aside from this Tracker library. (so I can't really make callbacks when the object is no longer needed)". Both of these statements can not be true. Out of the box Vue/React would know nothing of your tracker library so you must have instructed them on how to add to it. So instruct them to remove from it when they are done with the objects they added.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to store objects in a collection so that they are still garbage collected are WeakMaps. However you can't iterate them:

> Because of references being weak, WeakMap keys are not enumerable (i.e. there is no method giving you a list of the keys). If they were, the list would depend on the state of garbage collection, introducing non-determinism.
>      ~ [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap)

So no, this is not possible in js for good reasons.

Comment: You could keep a Array of the keys and then every so often remove those keys that aren't present in the WeakMap. Look we got back iteration and the non-determinism.

Comment: @dan d. Then youve got a reference in the array and they wont be gc'd ?! :)

Comment: The Array only has the keys not the values. The point of a WeakMap is that the values go away when there isn't another reference. A list of the keys is normally a lot smaller than the objects that tend to make up values.

Comment: @dan d. Nope it is not.

Comment: Ohh "WeakMaps" sounded so good until i read your description and then I was disappointed by the non iteration rule :)

Comment: Do immutable arrays help with garbage collection? https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns

Comment: @ryan yes i was disapointed too (actually wanted to add a magic answer instead of *nope, not possible*) but well its for a good reason and there are definetly other ways to solve this.

Comment: @jared there are no immutable arrays in javascript, what has redux todo with the question?

Comment: There are no native immutable arrays, the question is if doing deep copies using `Array.slice()` and map/reduce/filter frees the references. The link discusses the techniques in depth, including common problems. @Ryan